# Using Picasso with RoundedBitmapDrawable

Tags: android, picasso, roundedbitmapdrawable

I've seen Udacity lectures about Material Design and there was mentioned usage of [`RoundedBitmapDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/RoundedBitmapDrawable.html) to achieve circular view. However I have some troubles to make it work with `Picasso`.

I'm not sure how exactly `Picasso` works, but I have large, nonsquare image in file storage. Therefor I use `Picasso` as follows:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(f).resize(densityDpi, densityDpi).centerInside().transform(new Transformation() {
    @Override
    public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
        Log.d("jano", "transformation running");
        RoundedBitmapDrawable drawable = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(context.getResources(), source);
        drawable.setCircular(true);
        drawable.setCornerRadius(source.getWidth() / 2.0f);
        return drawable.getBitmap();
    }

    @Override
    public String key() {
        return "circle";
    }
}).into(imageView);
```

Images are however squared without rounded corners (should be circular). And That is what I want to achieve.

Is there any simple way to achieve this with `RoundedBitmapDrawable` or do I have to fully implement transformation? (which I have seen on StackOverflow)

Please do not submit answer without description why it cannot be used. I only want to know about combination of these 2 items (`Picasso`, `RoundedBitmapDrawable`)

Comment: you are already implementing a Transformation, what is exactly the issue ?

Comment: I'm sorry, edited... Images are squared not circular, that is problem

Comment: see [here](https://github.com/kingargyle/adt-leanback-support/blob/master/support-v4/src/main/java/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/RoundedBitmapDrawable.java) and find out what is returned by `RoundedBitmapDrawable#getBitmap`

Comment: remove `drawable.setCornerRadius(source.getWidth() / 2.0f);` and run it again

Comment: Nothing changed... Are Transformation applied after Picasso's resize and center is called?

Comment: did you see the sources and what is returned by `getBitmap` method?

Comment: @pskink Hmm I hope it is not original bitmap :|

Comment: hmm it is... so how to get correct Bitmap?

Comment: you can not, but you can call `setImageDrawable` on your `ImageView` when the `Bitmap` is loaded (in `transform` method or similar: i dont know picasso API)

Comment: so just remove `.into(imageView)` and add `imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable)` in `transform` method

Comment: Thanks for your assistance, at least I know where the problem is. still no success, but at least I know where to start

Answer (score 3):

I tried a lot to do the same but also not working... I guess is a problem during the getBitmap, anyway, I solved doing this:
(Note that the main difference is that I'm using a setImage as drawable and not converting to Bitmap as I said)

```
    Picasso.with(getContext())
    .load(mUser.user.profileImageUrl)
    .into(mProfileImage, new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            Bitmap source = ((BitmapDrawable) mProfileImage.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
            RoundedBitmapDrawable drawable =
                    RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(getContext().getResources(), source);
            drawable.setCircular(true);
            drawable.setCornerRadius(Math.max(source.getWidth() / 2.0f, source.getHeight() / 2.0f));
            mProfileImage.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError() {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Guys, my solution is going to work with call back, but now I understand the problem and can explain how to solve on the transformation: the .getBitmap() of RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory is going to return your original Bitmap, it saves the original status, so after you apply the circular modifications you are returning the original bitmap without changes. You can override your ImageView, on the method setDrawable to use RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory make circular, but you can't do on the setBitmap (because you can't get this as Bitmap, only the original and not rounded bitmap). Capiche ? ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use google IO app's BezelImageView which works well with the Picasso library, just add this class to your project and you can directly start using it like any other imageview, but bezelImageView has 2 extra options to specify the circle border color, and the mask drawable. Link to source code [here](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/BezelImageView.java) .

BezelImageView.java

```
/*
 * Copyright 2014 Google Inc. All rights reserved.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.google.samples.apps.iosched.ui.widget;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.ColorMatrix;
import android.graphics.ColorMatrixColorFilter;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.google.samples.apps.iosched.R;

/**
 * An {@link android.widget.ImageView} that draws its contents inside a mask and draws a border
 * drawable on top. This is useful for applying a beveled look to image contents, but is also
 * flexible enough for use with other desired aesthetics.
 */
public class BezelImageView extends ImageView {
    private Paint mBlackPaint;
    private Paint mMaskedPaint;

    private Rect mBounds;
    private RectF mBoundsF;

    private Drawable mBorderDrawable;
    private Drawable mMaskDrawable;

    private ColorMatrixColorFilter mDesaturateColorFilter;
    private boolean mDesaturateOnPress = false;

    private boolean mCacheValid = false;
    private Bitmap mCacheBitmap;
    private int mCachedWidth;
    private int mCachedHeight;

    public BezelImageView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public BezelImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public BezelImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        // Attribute initialization.
        final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.BezelImageView,
                defStyle, 0);

        mMaskDrawable = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.BezelImageView_maskDrawable);
        if (mMaskDrawable != null) {
            mMaskDrawable.setCallback(this);
        }

        mBorderDrawable = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.BezelImageView_borderDrawable);
        if (mBorderDrawable != null) {
            mBorderDrawable.setCallback(this);
        }

        mDesaturateOnPress = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.BezelImageView_desaturateOnPress,
                mDesaturateOnPress);

        a.recycle();

        // Other initialization.
        mBlackPaint = new Paint();
        mBlackPaint.setColor(0xff000000);

        mMaskedPaint = new Paint();
        mMaskedPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));

        // Always want a cache allocated.
        mCacheBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        if (mDesaturateOnPress) {
            // Create a desaturate color filter for pressed state.
            ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
            cm.setSaturation(0);
            mDesaturateColorFilter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean setFrame(int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        final boolean changed = super.setFrame(l, t, r, b);
        mBounds = new Rect(0, 0, r - l, b - t);
        mBoundsF = new RectF(mBounds);

        if (mBorderDrawable != null) {
            mBorderDrawable.setBounds(mBounds);
        }
        if (mMaskDrawable != null) {
            mMaskDrawable.setBounds(mBounds);
        }

        if (changed) {
            mCacheValid = false;
        }

        return changed;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (mBounds == null) {
            return;
        }

        int width = mBounds.width();
        int height = mBounds.height();

        if (width == 0 || height == 0) {
            return;
        }

        if (!mCacheValid || width != mCachedWidth || height != mCachedHeight) {
            // Need to redraw the cache.
            if (width == mCachedWidth && height == mCachedHeight) {
                // Have a correct-sized bitmap cache already allocated. Just erase it.
                mCacheBitmap.eraseColor(0);
            } else {
                // Allocate a new bitmap with the correct dimensions.
                mCacheBitmap.recycle();
                //noinspection AndroidLintDrawAllocation
                mCacheBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                mCachedWidth = width;
                mCachedHeight = height;
            }

            Canvas cacheCanvas = new Canvas(mCacheBitmap);
            if (mMaskDrawable != null) {
                int sc = cacheCanvas.save();
                mMaskDrawable.draw(cacheCanvas);
                mMaskedPaint.setColorFilter((mDesaturateOnPress && isPressed())
                        ? mDesaturateColorFilter : null);
                cacheCanvas.saveLayer(mBoundsF, mMaskedPaint,
                        Canvas.HAS_ALPHA_LAYER_SAVE_FLAG | Canvas.FULL_COLOR_LAYER_SAVE_FLAG);
                super.onDraw(cacheCanvas);
                cacheCanvas.restoreToCount(sc);
            } else if (mDesaturateOnPress && isPressed()) {
                int sc = cacheCanvas.save();
                cacheCanvas.drawRect(0, 0, mCachedWidth, mCachedHeight, mBlackPaint);
                mMaskedPaint.setColorFilter(mDesaturateColorFilter);
                cacheCanvas.saveLayer(mBoundsF, mMaskedPaint,
                        Canvas.HAS_ALPHA_LAYER_SAVE_FLAG | Canvas.FULL_COLOR_LAYER_SAVE_FLAG);
                super.onDraw(cacheCanvas);
                cacheCanvas.restoreToCount(sc);
            } else {
                super.onDraw(cacheCanvas);
            }

            if (mBorderDrawable != null) {
                mBorderDrawable.draw(cacheCanvas);
            }
        }

        // Draw from cache.
        canvas.drawBitmap(mCacheBitmap, mBounds.left, mBounds.top, null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void drawableStateChanged() {
        super.drawableStateChanged();
        if (mBorderDrawable != null && mBorderDrawable.isStateful()) {
            mBorderDrawable.setState(getDrawableState());
        }
        if (mMaskDrawable != null && mMaskDrawable.isStateful()) {
            mMaskDrawable.setState(getDrawableState());
        }
        if (isDuplicateParentStateEnabled()) {
            ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void invalidateDrawable(Drawable who) {
        if (who == mBorderDrawable || who == mMaskDrawable) {
            invalidate();
        } else {
            super.invalidateDrawable(who);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean verifyDrawable(Drawable who) {
        return who == mBorderDrawable || who == mMaskDrawable || super.verifyDrawable(who);
    }
}
```

Usage in layout.

```
<com.google.samples.apps.iosched.ui.widget.BezelImageView
                android:id="@+id/session_photo"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/dp"
                app:borderDrawable="@drawable/circle_stroke_only"
                app:maskDrawable="@drawable/circle_blue" />
```

circle_blue.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval"
    >
    <solid android:color="#00bcd4" />
</shape>
```

circle_stroke_only.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <stroke android:color="@color/theme_green" android:width="1dp"/>

</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent few hours with the exact same issue. The reason why it returns the same non-circle image is because it passed a bitmap with non-circle at first.

From the documentation of [RoundedBitmapDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/RoundedBitmapDrawable.html):

> getBitmap()
>
> Returns the bitmap used by this drawable to render.

So it is mean to return the original not-transformed bitmap.

**Solution**: Nothing! I ended up using a great library [picasso-transformations](https://github.com/wasabeef/picasso-transformations) with `CropCircleTransformation()`

Example:

```
 Picasso.with(mContext).load(url)
            .transform(new CropCircleTransformation())
            .into(holder_image);
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a solution for using RoundedBitmapDrawable by implementing a Target like this (instead of directly using .into(ImageView))

```
    Picasso.with(context)
                    .load("https://something.png")
                    .into( RoundCornersTargetProxy(my_avatar_imageview, 8f) )
```

with the Target implementation as follows

```
    class RoundCornersTargetProxy(val view: ImageView, val radius: Float): Target {
        override fun onPrepareLoad(placeHolderDrawable: Drawable?) {
            view.setImageDrawable(placeHolderDrawable)
        }

        override fun onBitmapFailed(errorDrawable: Drawable?) {
            view.setImageDrawable(errorDrawable)
        }

        override fun onBitmapLoaded(bitmap: Bitmap, from: Picasso.LoadedFrom?) {
            RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(Resources.getSystem(), bitmap).let {
                it.cornerRadius = radius
                view.setImageDrawable(it)
            }
        }

    }
```

This way you don't have to set it in the imageview just to get it out again.